# HAProxy redirect http://example.com and https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: https, haproxy, http-redirect

I have HAProxy configured to terminate SSL and send traffic to nginx instances. My HAProxy configuration is:

```
redirect scheme https code 301 if !letsenc !{ ssl_fc }
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

Currently, traffic to http://example.com goes to https://example.com

I would like to redirect to www. subdomain as follows:

http://example.com -> https://www.example.com

https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Can this be achieved with HAProxy without changing the nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [http-request redirect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20redirect) for such a redirect. This statement is similar to [redirect location](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#4.2-redirect%20location).

```
# shameless copy from the doc
http-request redirect code 301 location http://www.%[hdr(host)]%[capture.req.uri] unless { hdr_beg(host) -i www }
```

Comment: I added this to my demo haproxy.cfg running in a container and it's working as expected.